# I am not getting data from dynamodb using scan() nodejs

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to get the data where the product name is same and implementing the code by using nodejs.`

```
AWS.config.update({region : "us-east-1"});
    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params = {
        TableName: "ProductLocation",
        FilterExpression: "#pn = :a",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#pn": "Product_Name",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
             ":a" : "rava"
        }
    };

    console.log("Scanning Product_Name table.");
    docClient.scan(params, onScan);

    function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        // print all the movies
        console.log("Scan succeeded.");
        console.log(data);
        }
    }
```

Below is my dynamodb data
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ExpressionAttributeValues` should be:

```
{":a" : {S:"rava"}}
```

i.e. include the data type

Reference: [see the complete example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html)